# Strange wrong result for (un)coupled PDEs using MATLAB's pdepe, time is doubled

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, pde

I am trying to solve two coupled reaction diffusion equations in 1d, using pdpe, namely

$\partial_t u_1 = \nabla^2 u_1 + 2k(-u_1^2+u_2)$

$\partial_t u_2 = \nabla^2 u_1 + k(u_1^2-u_2)$

The solution is in the domain $x\in[0,1]$, with initial conditions being two identical Gaussian profiles centered at $x=1/2$. The boundary conditions are absorbing for both components, i.e. $u_1(0)=u_2(0)=u_1(1)=u_2(1)=0$.

Pdepe gives me a solution without prompting any errors. However, I think the solutions must be wrong, because when I set the coupling to zero, i.e. $k=0$ (and also if I set it to be very small, say $k=0.001$), the solutions do not coincide with the solution of the simple diffusion equation

$\partial_t u = \nabla^2 u$

as obtained from pdepe itself.

Strangely enough, the solutions $u_1(t)=u_2(t)$ from the "coupled" case with coupling set to zero, and the solution for the case uncoupled by construction $u(t')$ coincide if we set $t'=2t$, that is, the solution of the "coupled" case evolves twice as fast as the solution of the uncoupled case.

Here's a minimal working example:

**Coupled case**

```matlab
    function [xmesh,tspan,sol] = coupled(k) %argument is the coupling k

    std=0.001; %width of initial gaussian
    center=1/2; %center of gaussian

    xmesh=linspace(0,1,10000);
    tspan=linspace(0,1,1000);

    sol = pdepe(0,@pdefun,@icfun,@bcfun,xmesh,tspan);

        function [c,f,s] = pdefun(x,t,u,dudx)
            c=ones(2,1);

            f=zeros(2,1);
            f(1) = dudx(1);
            f(2) = dudx(2);

            s=zeros(2,1);
            s(1) = 2*k*(u(2)-u(1)^2);
            s(2) = k*(u(1)^2-u(2));
        end

        function u0 = icfun(x)
            u0=ones(2,1);
            u0(1) = exp(-(x-center)^2/(2*std^2))/(sqrt(2*pi)*std);
            u0(2) = exp(-(x-center)^2/(2*std^2))/(sqrt(2*pi)*std);
        end

        function [pL,qL,pR,qR] = bcfun(xL,uL,xR,uR,t)
            pL=zeros(2,1);
            pL(1) = uL(1);
            pL(2) = uL(2);

            pR=zeros(2,1);
            pR(1) = uR(1);
            pR(2) = uR(2);

            qL = [0 0;0 0];
            qR = [0 0;0 0];
        end

    end
```

**Uncoupled case**

```matlab
    function [xmesh,tspan,sol] = uncoupled()

    std=0.001; %width of initial gaussian
    center=1/2; %center of gaussian

    xmesh=linspace(0,1,10000);
    tspan=linspace(0,1,1000);

    sol = pdepe(0,@pdefun,@icfun,@bcfun,xmesh,tspan);

        function [c,f,s] = pdefun(x,t,u,dudx)
            c=1;

            f = dudx;

            s=0;
        end

        function u0 = icfun(x)
            u0=exp(-(x-center)^2/(2*std^2))/(sqrt(2*pi)*std);
        end

        function [pL,qL,pR,qR] = bcfun(xL,uL,xR,uR,t)
            pL=uL;

            pR=uR;

            qL = 0;
            qR = 0;
        end

    end
```

Now, suppose we run

```matlab
    [xmesh,tspan,soluncoupled] = uncoupled();
    [xmesh,tspan,solcoupled] = coupled(0); %coupling k=0, i.e. uncoupled solutions
```

One can directly check by plotting the solutions for any time index $it$ that, even if they should be identical, the solutions given by each function are not identical, e.g.

```matlab
    hold all
    plot(xmesh,soluncoupled(it+1,:),'b')
    plot(xmesh,solcoupled(it+1,:,1),'r')
    plot(xmesh,solcoupled(it+1,:,2),'g')
```

On the other hand, if we double the time of the uncoupled solution, the solutions are identical

```matlab
    hold all
    plot(xmesh,soluncoupled(2*it+1,:),'b')
    plot(xmesh,solcoupled(it+1,:,1),'r')
    plot(xmesh,solcoupled(it+1,:,2),'g')
```

The case $k=0$ is not singular, one can set $k$ to be small but finite, and the deviations from the case $k=0$ are minimal, i.e. the solution still goes twice as fast as the uncoupled solution.

I really don't understand what is going on. I need to work on the coupled case, but obviously I don't trust the results if it does not give the right limit when $k\to 0$. I don't see where I could be making a mistake. Could it be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source of the error. The problem lies in the qL and qR variables of bcfun for the coupled() function. The MATLAB documentation, see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/partial-differential-equations.html), is slightly ambiguous on whether the q's should be matrices or column vectors. I had used matrices

```matlab
        qL = [0 0;0 0];
        qR = [0 0;0 0];
```

but in reality I should have used column vectors

```matlab
        qL = [0;0];
        qR = [0;0];
```

Amazingly, pdpe didn't throw an error, and simply gave wrong results. This should perhaps be fixed by the developers.